# Sort generic list descending order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a method in my controller

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Posts.ToList());
    }
```

How can I get the list in descending order? Like instead of starting from id:1 it starts at the last id in the table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Posts.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Enumerable.OrderByDescending Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx)

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in descending order.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Posts.OrderByDescending(r=> r.id).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
db.Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.id).ToList();
```